# What kind of shoes are suitable for a Novice/Sprint triathlon?

Tags: equipment, running, cycling, swimming, triathlon

Next year in summer I want to take part in my first **triathlon**.
The distances will be **400m-750m swimming / 20km cycling / 2-5km running**.

Are there shoes that work for cycling (with click system) and running as well?

Or is it better to have two separate pairs that can be changed quickly?

(So far I have only done swimming and cycling, so I don't have any shoes for running yet.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For short course triathlon as you suggest it is not worth worrying this much about shoes.

Either use pedals with clips and straps (cages if you will) and ride in your running shoes, or else switch shoes in transition.

For your runners, they sell [stretchy laces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002AS9S7Q) so you can slip the shoes on, no need to retie the laces.

This will minimize transition time.

Running shoes that are properly fit to you are way more important than anything else.  You can ride a bike in sneakers or in road shoes, but you cannot run in improper shoes for very long.

Comment: Thanks geoffc. I got myself some well fitting running shoes and will give it a try with straps/cages and stretchy laces. Sounds like a good idea. :-)